# Trigger angular - Get status

Tags: angular, triggers

I have this trigger my component :

```
trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '400px', visibility: 'visible', overflow: 'auto' })),
      transition('void <=> *', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ]
```

I'm asking if there is any way to check this trigger status in MyComponent.ts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could actually bind the state to a local variable and transition between the defined states instead of `void <=> *`.

Controller

```js
@Component({
  ...,
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed', style({ height: '0px', minHeight: '0', visibility: 'hidden' })),
      state('expanded', style({ height: '400px', visibility: 'visible', overflow: 'auto' })),
      transition('collapsed <=> expanded', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class AppComponent {
  detailState = 'collapsed';    // <-- default state
  ...

  toggleState() {
    this.detailState = 'collapsed' ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed';
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<div [@detailExpand]="detailState"></div>

<button (mouseup)="toggleState()">Toggle</button>
```

Now the current state is in the variable `detailState`.